# Probability of normal distribution less than some value

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, math-software, confidence-interval

I've got quite confused with the following:

Find $$P(N(0,1)<1.96)$$

Is it true that $P(N(0,1)<1.96)=P(Z<1.96)$, where $Z\sim N(0,1)$?

Thus in R one would use the command pnorm(1.96)
?

Comment: yes, the $N(0,1) < 1.96$ event is shorthand for a standard normal random variable being less than 1.96.

Comment: If $Z$ is standard normal, you can find $P(Z < 1.96) = 0.9750$ using printed normal tables or software. Look in the margin of the printed table for row header `1.9` and at the column header of `.06`. The probability where they intersect will read  `.9750` (or perhaps `.4750`, if your table expects you to add 0.5 to get the CDF). In R statistical software `pnorm(1.96)` returns ` 0.9750021`. Also, some calculators will give the answer.